# ASP.NET HttpWebRequest - beginning today, rejected by Amazon with 503 exception

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

I have an affiliate account with Amazon and have been collecting information from the Amazon site for the purpose of sending them buyers. Today, I tested my site and found that all of the requests to Amazon failed. Here is the evidence:

1. I am using ASP.NET (VB) HttpWebRequest to gather the data. Provide it a URL, then use HttpWebResponse / GetResponseStream to retrieve the page.
2. Most of my Amazon data I get from the Amazon API (AWSECommerceService) - that service still works. Some data is not available from the API, which is why I resort to scraping.
3. As of today, any HttpWebRequest to any page on Amazon (even the home page) returns a 503 (Server Unavailable) exception. Those pages are all visible in any browser.
4. Every other Web site that I access still works (eBay, Barnes & Noble, etc.), so the problem is only with Amazon.

> Postulate: Amazon has programmed its
>   Web site to reject automated
>   inquiries. 
> Is there any way to spoof
>   the system and convince Amazon to send
>   the page?
>  Thanks and kudos to anyone who can shed some light!

NOTE: in researching the problem, I saw a suggestion to add a UserAgent parameter to the HttpWebRequest. I tried using a UserAgent code for IE8, but it made no difference. (UserAgent code found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

After some further testing, it turns out that this was happening because Amazon needs the Accept parameter of the `HttpWebRequest` to be specifically set. 
Just set it to:

```
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the UserAgent for the HTTPWebRequet before you make the call

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced exactly the same problem starting two days ago.

I've been using HttpWebRequest for years without any problems and also adding the Useragent parameter makes no difference.

The only solution I can come up with at present is to use a windows form with embedded webbrowser with some code like the following:-

```
Sub GetHTML

 WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.amazon.co.uk")

Application.DoEvents()

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Dim oDoc1
    Dim StrHTML As String

    oDoc1 = WebBrowser1.Document
    StrHTML = oDoc1.body.outerhtml
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. You're sending the request from a browser (WebBrowser1). The header identifies it as a browser, therefore Amazon responds as expected. Since I am using ASP.NET, I don't have the option of using WebBrowser. Is there a way I can attach a header to the HttpWebRequest that spoofs a browser?

Comment: I dunno mate. Whatever Amazon have implemented in the last few days it's expecting responses from an actual browser and if it doesn't get it, you end up with a 503 error. Hopefully a smart arse will come up with a better solution soon! ;) For me this solution works as my websites run off a database, so I can run this windows forms program to update my website. It aint great, but works at the moment.